# Linking issue in g++

Tags: c++, boost

I am writing code using C++ boost library, I am getting a linking error -

Code

```
#include "test/support/checkers/log-entry-presence-checkers.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>   
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

using namespace std;


namespace YumaTest
{
LogEntryPresenceChecker::LogEntryPresenceChecker(
    const vector<string>& expPresentText )
: checkStrings_( expPresentText )
{
}
LogEntryPresenceChecker::~LogEntryPresenceChecker()
{
}
void LogEntryPresenceChecker::operator()( const string& logFilePath ) const
{
     ifstream logFile;
     string line;
bool entryFound;

BOOST_FOREACH ( const string& val, checkStrings_ )
{
    entryFound = false;
    BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE( "\tChecking " << val << " is present" );
    logFile.open( logFilePath );
    if (logFile.is_open()) {
         while ( logFile.good() && entryFound == false ) {
            getline(logFile, line);
            if ( line.find( val ) != string::npos ) {
                entryFound = true;
            }
        }
        logFile.close();
    }
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL( true, entryFound );
}
}
```

Linking Error -

```
 g++ output/b64.o output/bobhash.o output/cap.o output/cfg.o output/cli.o output/conf.o output/def_reg.o output/dlq.o output/ext.o output/grp.o output/help.o output/json_wr.o output/log.o output/ncx_appinfo.o output/ncx.o output/ncx_feature.o output/ncx_list.o output/ncxmod.o output/ncx_num.o output/ncx_str.o output/obj.o output/obj_help.o output/op.o output/plock.o output/plock_cb.o output/rpc.o output/rpc_err.o output/runstack.o output/ses.o output/ses_msg.o output/status.o output/tk.o output/top.o output/tstamp.o output/typ.o output/val.o output/val_util.o output/var.o output/xml_msg.o output/xmlns.o output/xml_util.o output/xml_val.o output/xml_wr.o output/xpath1.o output/xpath.o output/xpath_wr.o output/xpath_yang.o output/yang.o output/yang_ext.o output/yang_grp.o output/yang_obj.o output/yang_parse.o output/yang_typ.o output/yin.o output/yinyang.o output/send_buff.o output/agt_acm.o output/agt.o output/agt_cap.o output/agt_cb.o output/agt_cfg.o output/agt_cli.o output/agt_commit_complete.o output/agt_connect.o output/agt_hello.o output/agt_if.o output/agt_ncx.o output/agt_not.o output/agt_plock.o output/agt_proc.o output/agt_rpc.o output/agt_rpcerr.o output/agt_ses.o output/agt_signal.o output/agt_state.o output/agt_sys.o output/agt_time_filter.o output/agt_timer.o output/agt_top.o output/agt_tree.o output/agt_util.o output/agt_val.o output/agt_val_parse.o output/agt_xml.o output/agt_xpath.o output/agt_yuma_arp.o output/agt_ncxserver.o output/checker-group.o output/string-presence-checkers.o output/log-entry-presence-checkers.o output/sil-callback-log.o output/callback-checker.o output/sil-callback-controller.o output/device-test-db.o output/device-test-db-debug.o output/state-data-test-db.o output/abstract-nc-session.o output/nc-base-query-test-engine.o output/nc-default-operation-config.o output/nc-query-test-engine.o output/nc-query-utils.o output/nc-strings.o output/yuma-op-policies.o output/abstract-global-fixture.o output/test-context.o output/base-suite-fixture.o output/query-suite-fixture.o output/simple-container-module-fixture.o output/simple-yang-fixture.o output/device-module-fixture.o output/device-get-module-fixture.o output/device-module-common-fixture.o output/state-get-module-fixture.o output/state-data-module-common-fixture.o output/cpp-unit-op-formatter.o output/log-utils.o output/ptree-utils.o output/base64.o output/NCMessageBuilder.o output/xpo-query-builder.o output/state-data-query-builder.o output/spoof-nc-session.o output/spoof-nc-session-factory.o output/running-cb-checker.o output/candidate-cb-checker.o output/integ-cb-checker-factory.o output/integ-fixture-helper.o output/integ-fixture-helper-factory.o output/simple-edit-tests.o output/default-none-tests.o output/simple-edit-running.o -Wall -g -lxml2 -lboost_unit_test_framework -Wl,--export-dynamic -o test-simple-edit-running
output/log-entry-presence-checkers.o: In function `YumaTest::LogEntryPresenceChecker::operator()(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const':
/home/abhishek/NETCONF_8_3_0/code/opensource/openyuma/netconf/test/integ-tests/../../test/support/checkers/log-entry-presence-checkers.cpp:52: undefined reference to `std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::open(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::_Ios_Openmode)'
output/log-entry-presence-checkers.o: In function `YumaTest::LogEntryNonPresenceChecker::operator()(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const':
/home/abhishek/NETCONF_8_3_0/code/opensource/openyuma/netconf/test/integ-tests/../../test/support/checkers/log-entry-presence-checkers.cpp:89: undefined reference to `std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::open(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::_Ios_Openmode)'
output/abstract-nc-session.o: In function `YumaTest::AbstractNCSession::concatenateLogFiles()':
/home/abhishek/NETCONF_8_3_0/code/opensource/openyuma/netconf/test/integ-tests/../../test/support/nc-session/abstract-nc-session.cpp:66: undefined reference to `std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ofstream(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::_Ios_Openmode)'
output/abstract-nc-session.o: In function `YumaTest::AbstractNCSession::appendLog(std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, unsigned short)':
/home/abhishek/NETCONF_8_3_0/code/opensource/openyuma/netconf/test/integ-tests/../../test/support/nc-session/abstract-nc-session.cpp:84: undefined reference to `std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ifstream(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::_Ios_Openmode)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am not getting why there is a error of undefined reference.

Please help me out How can I get rid of this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @sehe Not convinced that's helpful in this instance. Did you read the question?

Comment: Mmm. Maybe not close enough. "I am not getting why there is a error of undefined reference. Please help me out How can I get rid of this issue." made me decide. I agree it's funny business here

Comment: @sehe I think that FAQ is good for the usual flurry of generic link failures, but this one is potentially more nuanced. If nothing else, I cannot see a relevant answer there, though I skimmed.

Comment: You didn't hear me say otherwise :) Guess who upvoted

Comment: Are you using the exact same `g++` to link as was used to compile those object files?

Comment: Try reducing the amount of code? Does something like `int main() {std::ifstream(std::string("hehe"));}` work? [mcve]

Comment: Yes, you should be able to reproduce the problem with simply: `#include <fstream> #include <string> int main() { std::ifstream f(std::string("f")); }`

Comment: @Jonathan Error when compiling the program mentioned by you - `error: no matching function for call to âstd::basic_fstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_fstream(std::string)â
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-redhat-linux/4.4.1/../../../../include/c++/4.4.1/fstream:795: note: candidates are: std::basic_fstream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_fstream(const char*, std::_Ios_Openmode) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]`

Comment: @user2798118: Yep, looks like the same error. So there's your minimal testcase (see how debugging is critical?). Nothing to do with Boost it turns out.

Comment: Did you compile with -std=c++11? What GCC versions are you using? That constructor requires C++11 support. Your original error suggests that the `.o` files were compiled by a compiler with C++11 support, but the version you are using to link doesn't have it ... which is not supported, you must not link with an older G++ than you compiled with, ever. The error on the minimal example means either you didn't use `-std=c++11` or confirms that you're using an older GCC than was used to compile the `.o` files.

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely gcc-4.4.1 on fedora11

Comment: Facepalm. Are you a time traveller? That version of Fedora has been unsupported for many many years. Still, GCC 4.4.1 **does** support those constructors, so you shouldn't be getting that linker error. (The error on the minimal example is because you didn't use `-std=c++0x` to compile it).

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely Actually our product is currently using fedora 11 :(

Comment: What do you get if you compile the minimal example with `-std=c++0x` ?

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely `g++ -std=c++0x a.cpp
/tmp/cc27UnF0.o: In function `main':
a.cpp:(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to `std::basic_fstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_fstream(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::_Ios_Openmode)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
`

Comment: @ Jonathan Wakely Installed gcc version `rpm -qa | grep gcc
libgcc-4.4.1-2.fc11.i586
gcc-4.4.1-2.fc11.i586
gcc-c++-4.4.1-2.fc11.i586`

Comment: `rpm -q libstdc++` ?

Comment: `libstdc++-4.4.1-2.fc11.i586`

Comment: Very strange, looks like a bug in the RPM packages, which will never get fixed because you're on a dead version of Fedora. Bad luck.

Comment: I tried on Fedora 18, it is working fine. Thanks @Jonathan Wakely

Comment: Fedora 18 is also unsupported. If you want to work on old systems why not use something stable but still supported like CentOS? That has GCC 4.4.7 and the example compiles and links without problems.

Answer (score 2):

Did you copy/paste the object files or library files from somewhere? They must be built against the same binary interface.

This looks very much like you're using C++11 headers but a C++03 runtime, because your compiled code expects to find `ifstream` constructor overloads taking `std::string` (introduced in C++11), but the linker can find no evidence of implementation for such overloads.

Rebuild everything, including your Boost library, with the same toolchain and see what happens.

Comment: All object are created during compilation, After compilation I am trying to link them. I tried to link along with  **-std=c++11** also . Still I am getting the same error.

Comment: @user2798118: Yes I know what compilation is

Comment: `-std=c++11` is ignored during linking, there is only one runtime library, which works for both C++03 and C++11. The only way to get unresolved references to those C++11 constructors is to compile with one version of G++ and use an older version to link.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Okay thanks. That's what I was trying to get at regarding the runtime library (libs being compiled with an older GCC) - the `-std=c++11` was admittedly a bit silly though I did at least say it would be a hacky workaround if it worked :P